# System.Web.WebPages.Razor 3.0.0 missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, reference

I would like to add reference to my ASP.NET MVC4 project, but in Add reference dialog (Assemblies->Extensions), there are only version 1.0 and 2.0 of System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll

I have installed Visual Studio Professional 2013 and ASP.NET MVC4 from Web Platform Installer. What I am missing.

The web application does not work without this reference and complains that it cannot find System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll 3.0

Comment: Have you tried to install `Microsoft ASP.Net Web Pages` NUGET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor 3.0 is only compatible with MVC 5. In your question, you stated that you are using MVC 4, which is only compatible with Razor 2.0.

So, the real question is, why are you trying to add Razor 3.0 to MVC 4? Either stick with Razor 2.0, or upgrade your project to MVC 5.

If you have a project dependency that was designed for MVC 5 (and Razor 3.0), you might be getting this error. The same advice goes for the dependency - either change it to use Razor 2.0 and MVC 4 (assuming you can make changes to it), or upgrade the project that requires the dependency to MVC 5.